# Seems odd that Dev Story calls my blog post "Blogs or Videos"

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I have a few blog posts that were imported from my Careers CV. The type is "Blogs or Videos" which makes sense when I pick it at the top, but it seems odd for that to be included in the label above the item since it's not a "Blog or Video", it's a blog post.

Feature request: either don't display the type, or let me indicate which one it is so it can just say "Blog post" or similar.

[image]

**Update** Just noticed the same problem exists with "Features & Apps":

[image]

Comment: +1 - The culprit here looks to be that the "entry" bucket needs to include all types you could put there, but the "display" header looks weird if it says, "Ferrets, Ocelots, or other rodents not listed above."  In this case, the ideal would probably be a chooser that lets you indicate the sub-type to display (blog post or video), with an auto-selection if the url, (or open graph data, etc.) give enough info to make clear which it is.